# I'm trying to find where there is a "1" and to find the next "1" in a range

Tags: excel, vba

I have a small project I've been working on where I have a range of cells that have a status of either 1 or 0 for online and offline. What is the best method to look in a range of cells and go from a "1" to the next "1" and take the date and do some simple subtraction from the original date of offline to the next. I am assuming that -1 of that value will be the up-time of the equipment. Below is a copy of the code I've used and the layout of the excel worksheet that it pertains to.
If there are any better methods I am all ears. Still pretty new to VBA and I'm sure that what I wrote is not best practice.

```
Sub StatsRunner()


Dim weekStartDate As Date
Dim weekEndDate As Date
Dim monthEndDate As Date
Dim monthStartDate As Date
Dim augustStartDate As Date
Dim today As Date
Dim Rng As Range
Dim nextOnline As String
Dim nextOffline As String

weekStartDate = Now - 7
weekEndDate = Now + 1
monthEndDate = Now
monthStartDate = Now - 30
'43678 corresponds to the numeric value for the data 8/1/2019
janStartDate = 43831
today = Now

rowHolder = 6
statsFirstRow = Worksheets("Stats").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Worksheets("Stats").Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("E6:R2000").ClearContents

    For i = 6 To statsFirstRow

        If Worksheets("Stats").Cells(i, 1).Value >= weekStartDate _
         And Worksheets("Stats").Cells(i, 1).Value <= weekEndDate Then

         Worksheets("Stats").Range("A" & i & ":B" & i).Copy
         ActiveSheet.Range("E" & rowHolder & ":F" & rowHolder).Select
         ActiveSheet.Paste

         rowHolder = rowHolder + 1

       End If


    Next

        'This is for a single instance of item in a column
        weekEndRow = Worksheets("Stats").Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row
        If Worksheets("Stats").Range("F" & weekEndRow).Value = 0 And weekEndRow = 6 Then
            ActiveSheet.Range("P6").Value = 0

        ElseIf Worksheets("Stats").Range("F" & weekEndRow).Value = 1 And weekEndRow = 6 Then
            ActiveSheet.Range("P6").Value = 1

        End If

    'This next section tries to find the differences in each of the rows
    weekFirstRow = Worksheets("Stats").Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row

    For e = 6 To weekFirstRow

        'Used to hold the column for the weeks section where there will be integer addition/subtraction
        colHold = 6

        'Reintializes 'c' for a totals variable
        c = 0

            a = ActiveSheet.Cells(e, 5).Value
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(ActiveSheet.Range("F" & e + 1).Value) = True Then
            b = ActiveSheet.Cells(e + 1, 5).Value
            c = b - a
            ActiveSheet.Range("L" & e).Value = c

            Else:
            b = Now
            c = b - a
            ActiveSheet.Range("L" & e).Value = c
            End If

             End If

'         Else:
'         ActiveSheet.Range("L6").Value = 0
'         ActiveSheet.Range("P6").Value = 0
'
'        End If
    Next

'------------MONTH ITERATION-----------------------------------------

    rowHolder = 6

    For i = 6 To statsFirstRow

        If Worksheets("Stats").Cells(i, 1).Value >= monthStartDate _
         And Worksheets("Stats").Cells(i, 1).Value <= monthEndDate Then

         Worksheets("Stats").Range("A" & i & ":B" & i).Copy
         ActiveSheet.Range("G" & rowHolder & ":H" & rowHolder).Select
         ActiveSheet.Paste

         rowHolder = rowHolder + 1

       End If
    Next

       monthFirstRow = Worksheets("Stats").Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row

        For f = 6 To monthFirstRow

            c = 0

            If monthFirstRow > 6 And Worksheets("Stats").Cells(6, 8) = 1 Then

                If Worksheets("Stats").Cells(f, 8).Value = 1 Then

                    a = ActiveSheet.Cells(f, 7).Value
                    If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(ActiveSheet.Range("H" & f + 1).Value) = True Then
                    b = ActiveSheet.Cells(f + 1, 7).Value
                    c = b - a
                    ActiveSheet.Range("M" & f).Value = c

                    Else:
                    b = Now
                    c = b - a
                    ActiveSheet.Range("M" & f + 1).Value = c
                    End If

                End If

            Else
            ActiveSheet.Range("M6").Value = 0
            ActiveSheet.Range("Q6").Value = 0
            End If

       Next

'Use DateDiff to find the total hrs of availability from Jan 1st to current date.
        rowHolder = 6

        For i = 6 To statsFirstRow

            If Worksheets("Stats").Cells(i, 1).Value >= janStartDate _
            And Worksheets("Stats").Cells(i, 1).Value <= today Then

            Worksheets("Stats").Range("A" & i & ":B" & i).Copy
            ActiveSheet.Range("I" & rowHolder & ":J" & rowHolder).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste

            rowHolder = rowHolder + 1

            End If
       Next

       janFirstRow = Worksheets("Stats").Cells(Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Row

        For g = 6 To janFirstRow

            c = 0

            If janFirstRow > 6 And Worksheets("Stats").Cells(6, 10) = 1 Then

                If Worksheets("Stats").Cells(g, 10).Value = 1 Then
                a = ActiveSheet.Cells(g, 9).Value
                If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(ActiveSheet.Range("J" & g + 1).Value) = True Then
                b = ActiveSheet.Cells(g + 1, 9).Value
                c = b - a
                ActiveSheet.Range("N" & g).Value = c

                Else:
                b = Now
                c = b - a
                ActiveSheet.Range("N" & g + 1).Value = c
                End If
            End If

            Else
            ActiveSheet.Range("N6").Value = 0
            ActiveSheet.Range("R6").Value = 0
            End If

       Next

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: You could use the `Find` method.

Comment: ^ more specifically: [`Range.FindNext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.findnext). Thought, looking at your data I noticed an `AutoFilter`, which you can also use to got through visible cells after implementing a criteria to the filter.

Comment: or use `match` to look for the 0 from the 1 of interest, then simple arithmetic

Comment: Ok, thank you for the quick responses here! I'll start doing some research online for the advice given.